# Resizing iframes

Tags: jquery, iframe

I know this question has been asked before in some form or another, and I also know iframes are evil, but in this particular instance I have no other option. I need to develop and iframe that pulls a small form widget from another domain. The width of the widget is fixed, but it contains panels the slide open and shut using jquery. Is there a way of getting the iframe to expand and contract according to what's happening with the iframes content?
Thanks.

Comment: Not without “help” from the other domain, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: can you edit the page inside the iframe?

Comment: this is what you need then: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: This looks bang on. Thanks mate. I'll have a play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can edit the content of the page inside the iframe, you can use this jQuery plugin to communicate between the frame and the parent window:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for your help. Looks just the job.

Answer (score 1):

Having had much the same issue and not finding an answer that solved all my use cases, I ended up writing a simple library to handle this.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll check it out.